# Data in update panel is not save in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to save the data in my modal with is in an update panel to my database.

The value in my textbox are behind save in there variable but there are not save in the database. I do not know why. I use an `updModal.Update();` each time because the modal is getting from the database via a list view.

Here is my modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="studinfo" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Student Info</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close"
                    data-dismiss="modal">
                    &times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <contenttemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

                    <div class="card h-100">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:Panel ID="typepannel" CssClass="list-group-item" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbltype" runat="server"
                                        Font-Bold="true" Text="Candidate Type: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="type" runat="server"
                                        Text=''>
                                    </asp:Label>

                                </asp:Panel>

                                <asp:Panel ID="colpanel" CssClass="list-group-item" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCol" runat="server"
                                        Font-Bold="true" Text="College Attend: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="college" runat="server"
                                        Text=''>
                                    </asp:Label>

                                </asp:Panel>

                                <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"
                                        Font-Bold="true" Text="Name: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server"
                                        Text=''>
                                    </asp:Label>

                                </div>

                                <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNic" runat="server"
                                        Font-Bold="true" Text="Nic: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Nic" runat="server"
                                        Text=''>
                                    </asp:Label>

                                </div>

                                <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server"
                                        Font-Bold="true" Text="Age: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Age" runat="server"
                                        Text=''>
                                    </asp:Label>

                                </div>

                                <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblAdress" runat="server"
                                        Font-Bold="true" Text="Address: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Address" runat="server"
                                        Text=''>
                                    </asp:Label>

                                </div>

                                <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblacad" runat="server"
                                        Font-Bold="true" Text="Academy: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Academy" runat="server"
                                        Text=''>
                                    </asp:Label>
                                </div>

                                <h6 class="mt-3 mb-3">Parent in Charge</h6>
                                <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblParent" runat="server"
                                        Font-Bold="true" Text="Parent Name: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="parentName" runat="server"
                                        Text=''>
                                    </asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNumber" runat="server"
                                        Font-Bold="true" Text="Parent Contact Number: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Number" runat="server"
                                        Text=''>
                                    </asp:Label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server"
                                        Font-Bold="true" Text="Parent Email Address: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Email" runat="server"
                                        Text=''>
                                    </asp:Label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server"
                                        Font-Bold="true" Text="Result: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlResult"
                                        CssClass="select form-control"
                                        runat="server">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>

                                </div>


                                <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMarks" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Marks: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMarks"
                                        CssClass="form-control form-control-lg" />
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvMarks" runat="server"
                                        Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtMarks"
                                        SetFocusOnError="true"
                                        ErrorMessage="Marks is Mandatory">
                                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpVMarks" runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtMarks"
                                        Operator="DataTypeCheck"
                                        Type="Double"
                                        SetFocusOnError="true"
                                        Display="Dynamic"
                                        Text="Incorect data type"
                                        ForeColor="Red"
                                        ErrorMessage="Invalid">
                                    </asp:CompareValidator>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPhone"
                                        runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtMarks"
                                        SetFocusOnError="true"
                                        Display="Dynamic"
                                        ForeColor="Red"
                                        ValidationExpression="^\d\d+(\.[1-9])?$"
                                        ErrorMessage="Invalid">

                                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </div>
                                <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblpurcentage" runat="server"
                                        Font-Bold="true" Text="Purcentage : "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtpur"
                                        CssClass="form-control form-control-lg" />
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                                        ID="rfvpur" runat="server"
                                        Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtpur"
                                        SetFocusOnError="true"
                                        ErrorMessage="Purcentage is Mandatory">
                                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvpur" runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtpur"
                                        Operator="DataTypeCheck"
                                        Type="Double"
                                        SetFocusOnError="true"
                                        Display="Dynamic"
                                        Text="Incorect data type"
                                        ForeColor="Red"
                                        ErrorMessage="Invalid">
                                    </asp:CompareValidator>
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                 
                                            </ContentTemplate>

                </asp:UpdatePanel>

                   <asp:Button ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click" CausesValidation="false"
                        CssClass="btn btn-success btn-block" runat="server" Text="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the code behind of the save button:

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            updModal.Update();

           
            string id = txtId.Text;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "update tblStudent set stud_result=@res,stud_purcentage=@pur,stud_totalMarks=@marks where stud_Id=@id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@res", ddlResult.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pur", txtpur.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marks", txtMarks.Text.Trim());
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            Label1.Text = txtId.Text;
            gridView();
          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "LaunchServerSide",
                      "$(function () { showUErrorModal(); });", true);

        }
        finally
        {

            con.Close();

        }

    }
```

Comment: any error which you getting javascript or C#.

Comment: No error. It is just not sending the value to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Label1.Text = txtId.Text; you write `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`